# Which preposition to choose for referring to the means of doing an action (by, with, using, via, over)?

Tags: prepositions

What is the best option to say that I will send you an update and I will use email in order to do it? What sound more natural?

1. I will send you an update later **via email**
2. I will send you an update later **over email**
3. I will send you an update later **by email**
4. I will send you an update later **with email**
5. I will send you an update later **using email**

The same question, but to say that a file was compressed, and rar was used to do it

1. The file should be compressed **via rar**
2. The file should be compressed **by rar**
3. The file should be compressed **with rar**
4. The file should be compressed **using rar**

Is there any rule?

Comment: Perhaps the best option of all isn't listed: _I will email you an update later_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though all the prepositions you are suggesting  are used, the most common ones are ***by email and via email*** as shown ***[here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=via%20email%2Cby%20email%2Cusing%20email%2C%20over%20email%2C%20with%20email&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvia%20email%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cby%20email%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cusing%20email%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cover%20email%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20email%3B%2Cc0).***

[file compressed with](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22file%20compressed%20with%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1998,cd_max:2007&lr=lang_en) is commonly used, other options like *by  or using* are fine.

Comment: Your answer seems to answer to the first half of the question. Though using the same method will achieve the second half of the question, you should do the work here so that the others will get the answer right away without having to do this method.

Comment: And what is better with compression? It looks like the situation with file compression is much less clear - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=file+is+compressed+by%2Cfile+is+compressed+with%2Cfile+is+compressed+using&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfile%20is%20compressed%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfile%20is%20compressed%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfile%20is%20compressed%20using%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @DimanNe - this is probably clearer: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=file++compressed+by%2Cfile+compressed+with%2Cfile+compressed+using&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfile%20compressed%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfile%20compressed%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfile%20compressed%20using%3B%2Cc0

Comment: It's worth noting that those are the most common ones found _in writing_. Ngrams won't tell us what is uttered allowed in the hallways and in parking lots – although, in this case, I'm guessing it's roughly the same.

Comment: Please see [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/440989/is-the-word-hitherto-outdated/440994#comment1058863_440994) regarding *Google Books Ngram Viewer* results outside the 1800–2000 year range.

Comment: @userr2684291 - whatever the case, the same conclusions still hold : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=via+email%2Cby+email%2Cusing+email%2Cover+email%2Cwith+email&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvia%20email%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cby%20email%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cusing%20email%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cover%20email%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20email%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @userr2684291 and - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=file+compressed+by%2Cfile+compressed+with%2Cfile+compressed+using&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfile%20compressed%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfile%20compressed%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfile%20compressed%20using%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @user5768790 Sure, I'm just telling you for future reference.

Comment: @userr2684291 - not sure what you mean, anyway thanks.

Comment: @user5768790 https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for%20future%20reference

Comment: @userr2684291 - I see, you are joking..

Comment: @user5768790 I'm not joking; I have no idea what you're having trouble understanding in my previous comments, however. Tell me so that I can try and explain.